# insert php in jquery script

Tags: php, jquery

this jquery script not work when im insert php tag into this,.. can i know what is the problem..

```
<script language="javascript">

    $("#openmsg_<?php echo $id; ?>").click(function(){
        $("#toggleText_<?php echo $id; ?>").toggle(800);
    })

</script>
```

this is my jquery code to toggle

```
<form action="my_messages.php" method="POST" name="<?php echo $msg_title; ?>">
<input type="button" name="openmsg" id="openmsg_<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $msg_title; ?>" onClick="javascript:toggle<?php echo $id; ?>();" />
<input type="submit" name="setopened_<?php echo $id; ?>" value="I have read this" />
</form>

<div id="toggleText_<?php echo $id; ?>" style="display:none;">
<?php echo $msg_body; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `$id` where is it defined?

Comment: can't do that, php codes only work in ".php" files, the way to go is to put the values that are inserted by php inside an `<input type="hidden">` and then get the value from that inside jQuery.

Comment: Are you aware of the differences between client-side and server-side code? You are not expecting $id to use a javascript variable are you?

Comment: i know how it do with javascript but i wnt to know how to creat with j query? :/ in inspect eliment of page showin id correctly but toggle not work ...

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code, can you provide us with a link or something, so that we can check it out?

Comment: sorry i connot do it brother.. there have lot of pages ,, i wnt to know that is it posible to join php code with jquery like this script

Comment: Why not use classes to attach click handler?

Comment: You have attached a handler to the "openmsg_<id>" element's click event twice... both with jQuery and within the html tag. Is this right?

Comment: Also, try defining your click handler inside `$(document).ready()`. It is possible the DOM has not finished loading when that script is run and so there is no such element at the time to hook the handler to.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this :

$("#openmsg_"+).click(function(){
        $("#toggleTextuserid_"+).toggle(800);
    })

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script language="javascript">

var id = <?php echo $id?>;

    $("#openmsg_" + id + "").click(function(){
        $("#toggleTextuserid_" + id + "").toggle(800);
    })

</script>
```

Comment: did you try debug it? If there is any other problem?

Comment: yes brother i did not found any other problem,.. and as your code when id insert in to selector id values is not showing as number it showing as text (id)

Comment: ok I am going to try it. What do you want to do with this code? What is the purpose?

Comment: i wnt to check brother is it posible to insert php code in jquery like
my script :)

Comment: tell me what you have and what you want to show or make. Maybe we will find other way to do it.

Comment: i know how it do with javascript but i wnt to know how to creat with j query? :/ in inspect eliment of page showin id correctly but toggle not work

Comment: for example you have other id in div `<div id="toggleText_<?php echo $id; ?>"` and in JS `$("#toggleTextuserid_<?php echo $id; ?>").toggle(800);` i think this: **userid**

Comment: no that mistake when i insert the post that mistake is not my real code